# Relative links that changes only parent dir

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there any way to write such relative link, that changes only parent of current directory? Like when we have domain.com/parentone/pageone and we need to go to domain.com/parenttwo/pageone ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relative links in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460450/relative-links-in-html)

Comment: try this `../../parenttwo/pageone` (assuming link is inside html located under `/parentone/pageone`)

Comment: thanks for comment, but i'm looking for solution, where i don't need to write children directly. I don't know if it really possible, but i need smith like 
href="../../parenttwo/*" where * will automatically detect current page, and place it into link

Comment: @ЛысенкоАлексей, no you will need custom javascript for this functionality, to extract the basename from current url and apply to all other relative urls (e.g on a click event)

Comment: better yet make a function eg `relative_current(path)`  which computed automaticaly the needed relative path and use the function as url in your links instead of hardcoding relative paths (e.g in php or even with js) as in `<a href="#" rel="../../parenttwo" onclick="this.href=relative_current(this.rel);return true;"></a>`